# How can I replace every second digit to another digit using if else statement in php?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, replace

I have a number that a user will put into a form - 12 digits. Every second digit needs to be replaced - if the digit is:
1 then make it 5
2 then make it 1
3 then make it 6
4 then make it 2
5 then make it 7
6 then make it 3
7 then make it 8
8 then make it 4
0 and 9 stay the same.

So for example:
343608111218 will end up being 383307121417.

Here is an example of what I'm currently doing, but I think it is long winded. This is just for the first number, so I'm assuming I could do something else?

```
$_POST['number'] = '343608111218';
preg_match_all('~(\d)~', $_POST['number'], $pregs);

if($pregs[1][1] === "1") {
$one = 5;
} 
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "2"){
$one = 1;
}
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "3"){
$one = 6;
}
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "4"){
$one = 2;
}
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "5"){
$one = 7;
}
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "6"){
$one = 3;
}
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "7"){
$one = 8;
}
elseif ($pregs[1][1] === "8"){
$one = 4;
}
$rep1 = (array_replace($pregs[1],array(1=>$one)));
```

If there is a way that I can reduce the amount of code, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the output should be `383307121417` from the given input of `343608111218`?

Comment: Yea even I am Confused with this :D Also this is so basic. I wonder why is this a problem! PS:- There are really good answers below.

Comment: Yeah, it is basic, but everytime I start thinking about it, I OVER think, and end up in circles!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it is with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), passing the match of 2 digits in a row and using [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace the 2nd digit appropriately:

```
$_POST['number'] = '343608111218';

echo preg_replace_callback('~(\d)(\d)~', function ($m) {
    return $m[1] . strtr($m[2], '12345678', '51627384');
}, $_POST['number']);
```

Output:

```
323304151114
```

This is based on the description you gave on how to do replacements. However if your expected output reflects the correct way to do the replacements, the replacements have to be the other way around, which is just a question of changing the order of parameters to `strtr`:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~(\d)(\d)~', function ($m) {
    return $m[1] . strtr($m[2], '51627384', '12345678');
}, $_POST['number']);
```

Output:

```
383307121417
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/phu1P)

Answer (score 2):

As you are replacing each digit with another, create a lookup string and use the number as the index to the array, all the positions 0-9 are set - even if they are the same value.  As the value is a string, you can just use the value as the position of the string and replace it directly...

```
$value = $_POST['number'];
$trans = "0516273849";
for ( $i = 1; $i < strlen($value); $i+=2 )  {
    $value[$i] = $trans[$value[$i]];
}
echo $value;
```

**Edit:**

To achieve what is the 'desired' output (although only a guess as to what this should be) you can change the line to...

```
$trans = "0246813579";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$transform = array(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 5,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 6,
    4 => 8,
    5 => 7,
    6 => 3,
    7 => 8,
    8 => 4,
    9 => 9
);
$number = '343608111218';
$num = array_map('intval', str_split($number));
$i = 1;
foreach ($num as $key => $value) {

    if (0 == ($i % 2)) {
        echo $transform[$value];
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To modernize and refine Nick's regex script, use `\K` to eliminate the use of capture groups. Arrow function syntax helps to make the script more concise. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iAiWm))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/.\K\d/',
         fn($m) => strtr($m[0], '12345678', '51627384'),
         $_POST['number']
     );
```

---

Nigel's answer is optimized for performance. Despite counting the string length on every iteration and unnecessarily replacing certain numbers with the same number, it will perform very swiftly because it only makes iterated calls of `count()`. Because all characters in the input string and the translation string are expected to be single-byte characters, the cooresponding number in the translation string can be accessed by its offset. Here's my version of Nigel's script ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iUr15))

```
$value = '343608111218';
$trans = '0516273849';

for ($i = 1, $len = strlen($value); $i < $len; $i += 2) {
    $value[$i] = $trans[$value[$i]];
}
echo $value;
```

---

Mujuonly's answer can be boiled down a little further. `$var & 1` is a bitwise odd check which is just as cryptic as `!($var % 2)`, but is slightly faster (not noticeably). Casting each character as an integer is not necessary and using a string-type translation source is a more succinct technique. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/k58RF))

```
$number = '343608111218';
$trans = '0516273849';

foreach (str_split($number) as $i => $d) {
    if ($i & 1) {
        $number[$i] = $trans[$d];
    }
}
echo $number;
```